# ./runjava not recognized on windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, github, jar

I am trying to run a java program on a text file got from this github page-

https://github.com/dbamman/book-nlp

This is the command it asks me to run -

```
./runjava novels/BookNLP -doc data/originalTexts/dickens.oliver.pg730.txt -printHTML -p data/output/dickens -tok data/tokens/dickens.oliver.tokens -f
```

I have followed the other instructions and run the file from the book-nlp-master folder (I have downloaded the zip file)

This command worked on Linux as far as I remember, but on Windows cmd it gives me this error-

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If i switch the slashes as they are given in windows, it gives me -

```
'.\runjava' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I fix this. I ran this on Linux and it worked for me, but I don't remember what I did.

P.S. running 'runjava' gave the same error.

Comment: I did, I got 'runjava' not recognized

Comment: runjava is a shell script, you are on windows.

Comment: runjava is a shell script to linux. You need to adapt it to windows, and name it runjava.bat

Comment: @anolsi this won't fix it, there would be shell code in a .bat file.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Yes, I know, because of that I said "you need to adapt it". The rename is only meant to not change the original one...

Comment: Will using cygwin work?

Comment: @NikhilPrabhu probably, or try running directly java -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -Xmx3000m -ea book-nlp.jar

Comment: as long as you're in that directory: `java -cp book-nlp.jar;lib/* novels.BookNLP -doc dat...`

Comment: That gave me an exception :/

Comment: @NikhilPrabhu You got an exception running with cygwin? Or running it directly?

Comment: @anolsi directly... I had the same issue in linux which i fixed with chmod. How could I do the same in windows?

Comment: But which exception was? Please update your question with that...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Bash script with Windows, I suggest you use Git Bash. Git Bash is provided with Git installation for Windows.

Git : https://git-scm.com/downloads

Answer (score 0):

You use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or Powershell which comes with the Github for Windows.